# How to use Twilio to do some automation, and then let a human converse?

Tags: sms, twilio, chatbot, twilio-api

I'm a 100% newbie with Twilio but trying to help someone out.
We have a website where someone fills out a form and it kicks off some automated texts.  First we want some automated back and forth (at the moment this is being done by our website built on bubble.io, but we could switch it to Twilio if need be).
At the end of the automated conversation, we want a human to then step in and have a human conversation.

Is this possible?  How would I do that?

We're open to any platform.

Answer (score 1):

take a look at this part of the Twilio documentation, it may provide additional insight into what you are attempting. Studio is good for the initial human<>bot interaction but at some point for 2-way dialog, you will need to introduce Programmable Chat.

How to hand-off messaging conversations from Autopilot to your Contact Center
https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off

Answer (score 1):

To achieve your goal try following five steps:

1. [Hand-off documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off)
2. [send-to-agent-action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off?code-sample=code-send-to-agent-action-5&code-language=JSON&code-sdk-version=default)
3. [send-to-agent-function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off?code-sample=code-send-to-agent-function-5&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default)
4. [Build Agent Hand-off](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off?code-sample=code-send-to-agent-function-5&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default#6-build-agent-hand-off)
5. [Complete the hand-off](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off?code-sample=code-send-to-agent-function-5&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default#complete-the-hand-off)

To sum up, you need to go through several steps. First of all, visit [1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off) this link (although there might be need of this link to do miscellaneous tasks until to achieve your final output). After going to [1](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off) this link follow the steps (side navigation menu) as per as your need. The documentation is well directed. Then follow the rest links i have mentioned (go one by one from [2](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off?code-sample=code-send-to-agent-action-5&code-language=JSON&code-sdk-version=default) to [5](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/guides/how-to-hand-off?code-sample=code-send-to-agent-function-5&code-language=Node.js&code-sdk-version=default#complete-the-hand-off). These are the things you have to go through each of them to achieve your goal).

That's all. Hopefully, it'll be helpful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

This question is too open-ended to really answer, but sounds like a good use case for  [Twilio Studio](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio), which is a GUI interface to the Twilio API and has widgets to gather text input, make http requests to send that input wherever you need, and connect the user to an agent afterwards.